# Rogue entries in TypeSpec metadata table

Tags: .net, clr, metadata

I have a .NET library and I am trying to understand more about the inner workings of .NET. So I am going through ECMA-335 specification and utilizing the CFF Explorer VII.

My question is, in the TypeSpec table the Signature is an index in to the Blob heap and should be a TypeSpec signature as described in section 23.2.14. Which means it can be a PTR, FNPTR, ARRAY, SZARRAY, GENERICINSTANCE (ELEMENT_TYPE_ removed for brevity).

However I have two entries in this TypeSpec table that are seemingly not referenced by any other table in the metadata and are of type VAR 0x13 and MVAR 0x1e.

This assembly is compiled in VS2010 against .NET 4.

The ECMA-335 would lead me to believe this is an error but it has been compiled using the MS C# compiler.

Does anyone know what they are and what they mean?

**Update:**

After lots of messing around this code creates those two entries in the TypeSpec table.

```
public class AllOutputTypesClass<T> {
    public void GenericMethod<N>(N anItem) {
        string s = anItem.ToString();
    }

    public string GenericMethod<N>(T anItem, N secondItem) {
        return anItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've observed the same thing. It seems to me that MVAR and VAR are just missing from section 23.2.14 of the spec. Is this your conclusion too or am I maybe missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ILDasm you can get a good breakdown of the methods, go to the View -> Meta Info -> select More Hex.  Then go to the View -> Meta Info -> Show!

Here is the breakdown for the second method:

```
    Method #2 (06000002) 
-------------------------------------------------------
    MethodName: GenericMethod (06000002)
    Flags     : [Public] [HideBySig] [ReuseSlot]  (00000086)
    RVA       : 0x0000206c
    ImplFlags : [IL] [Managed]  (00000000)
    CallCnvntn: [DEFAULT]
    hasThis 
    generic 
    Type Arity:1 
    ReturnType: String
    2 Arguments
        Argument #1:  Var!0
        Argument #2:  MVar!!0
    Signature : 30 01 02 0e 13 00 1e 00 
    1 Generic Parameters
        (0) GenericParamToken : (2a000003) Name : N flags: 00000000 Owner: 06000002
    2 Parameters
        (1) ParamToken : (08000002) Name : anItem flags: [none] (00000000)
        (2) ParamToken : (08000003) Name : secondItem flags: [none] (00000000)
```

If you scroll down further you'll see the TypeSpec table entries too.

### TypeSpec #1 (1b000001)

```
TypeSpec : MVar!!0
Signature: 1e 00
```

### TypeSpec #2 (1b000002)

```
TypeSpec : Var!0
Signature: 13 00
```

What ILdasm shows above is the VAR (13 00) is the generic !T passed at the class level (generic param in type definition) and the MVAR (1e 00) is the generic !!N passed at the method level (generic param in method definition).

However ... you already know that much, Orion has your answer - the entries in the TypeSpec table are being used in the IL.  One entry is used in one method and the other is the other method.  You can see this in ILdasm when you look at the methods:

```
    .method /*06000001*/ public hidebysig instance void 
        'GenericMethod'<'N'>(!!'N' 'anItem') cil managed
// SIG: 30 01 01 01 1E 00
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals /*11000001*/ init ([0] string 's')
  IL_0000:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_0001:  /* 0F   | 01               */ ldarga.s   'anItem'
  IL_0003:  /* FE16 | (1B)000001       */ constrained. !!'N'/*1B000001*/
  IL_0009:  /* 6F   | (0A)000011       */ callvirt   instance string ['mscorlib'/*23000001*/]'System'.'Object'/*01000001*/::'ToString'() /* 0A000011 */
  IL_000e:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
  IL_000f:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method 'AllOutputTypesClass`1'::'GenericMethod'
```

and

```
.method /*06000002*/ public hidebysig instance string 
        'GenericMethod'<'N'>(!'T' 'anItem',
                             !!'N' 'secondItem') cil managed
// SIG: 30 01 02 0E 13 00 1E 00
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x206c
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals /*11000001*/ init ([0] string 'CS$1$0000')
  IL_0000:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_0001:  /* 0F   | 01               */ ldarga.s   'anItem'
  IL_0003:  /* FE16 | (1B)000002       */ constrained. !'T'/*1B000002*/
  IL_0009:  /* 6F   | (0A)000011       */ callvirt   instance string ['mscorlib'/*23000001*/]'System'.'Object'/*01000001*/::'ToString'() /* 0A000011 */
  IL_000e:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
  IL_000f:  /* 2B   | 00               */ br.s       IL_0011
  IL_0011:  /* 06   |                  */ ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method 'AllOutputTypesClass`1'::'GenericMethod'
```

The 0x1b table is the TypeSpec, so the following lines from the methods above show the usage of the 2 rows you were wondering about:

```
  IL_0003:  /* FE16 | (1B)000001       */ constrained. !!'N'/*1B000001*/
```

and

```
IL_0003:  /* FE16 | (1B)000002       */ constrained. !'T'/*1B000002*/
```

Comment: I think I will be using ILDasm a little bit more in future. It is still annoying that these are not mentioned in the ECMA-335 document.

Comment: It is in the ECMA-335 spec, look at 22.21 GenericParamContraint 0x2C and search the document for TypeDefOrRef and/or TypeDefOrRefEncoded.

Comment: The GenericParamConstraint table described at 22.21 mentions the index to the TypeSpec table, however that table contains no entries. Verified in ILDasm and CFF Explorer. The TypeSpec signiture blob does not mention the signitures VAR and MVAR as valid. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The contents of TypeSpec represent signatures for the instantiation of the generic type/method, so you'll only see direct references to the TypeSpec table from the GenericParamConstraint table (if there are any) in the metadata tables themselves.  If you look at the IL, then find the reference and usages of the signatures (pointers) stored in the TypeSpec table.  Try locating the bytes in a hex editor - that way you only see the byte code and then it is easier to see the refrences to the TypeSpec records.

Answer (score 4):

Both TypeSpec tokens in your example are referenced from the IL in the method implementations, not from the metadata. For example, the IL for one of your methods looks like this:

```
.method public hidebysig instance string 
        GenericMethod<N>(!T anItem,
                         !!N secondItem) cil managed
{
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (string V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarga.s   anItem
  IL_0003:  constrained. !T
  IL_0009:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_000e:  stloc.0
  IL_000f:  br.s       IL_0011
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method AllOutputTypesClass`1::GenericMethod
```

The TypeSpec token is used to represent the "!T" in the constrained prefix. You'll see a similar reference to the other TypeSpec token in the body of the other method.